# Automatically refresh imported macros in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently updating multiple separate excel documents to use macros.

While each of these documents are separate there are a number of equations shared amongst them. To make my life easier I've exported my macros to a bas file which is then imported into each subsequent file. The issue I have at the moment is that occasionally some of these equations need to be changed or updated. This currently results in me having to go to every excel file, delete the previously imported bas file and reimport the new one. Is there a way to import the bas file through some form of symbolic link or to force Excel to check the location of the file and ensure that the bas file is up to date.

Below is a simple use case, as I may have been rather unclear in my ramblings :

Document 1 has one equation
Macros: 
   Equation 1 : (value1 + value2) / value1

This is exported to macros.bas

Document 2 uses the same Macro and thus just imports macros.bas:
   Equation 1 : (value1 + value2) / value1

Two days later I am informed that the equation should be modified such that the equation is divided by value2. To do this the following steps are performed.

Step 1)
The bas file is updated such that 
   Equation 1 : (value1 + value2) / value2

Step 2) 
Document 1 and Document 2 are opened
Step 3) 
I have to delete the old macros module and reimport the new one.

Is there a way to automate Step 2 - 3, through symbolic linking or forcing excel to automatically refresh imported macros from the macros.bas ?

Thank you for any response.

Comment: It sounds to me as though you should be using an add-in to store the shared code rather than putting it into each workbook. That way you only need to update code in one place.

Comment: Thank you. 

I'll look into it and post my solution when done.

Comment: I've had this issue before - What I did was distribute workbooks that call macros in a centralised workbook that I controlled so it wouldn't matter how long ago they received the workbook, it would remain current because it'd be calling a macro I could manage. That doesn't solve the issue to hand but it stops it from happening again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Rory the answer to this question lies in the use of Add-Ins
Kudos to the following stack overflow article for guidance.
[running a macro from an add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814116/running-a-macro-from-an-add-in)

Here is the solution that I ended up performing.

Create a completely new workbook. This will store all the modules that need to be shared.

```
1 - In the Developer tab select Visual Basic.
2 - Create the module/modules I want to store my macros in and start writing them.
3 - Save the Workbook selecting the type "Excel Add-In (*.xlam)"
4 - Open the Workbook I wish to actually work on. 
5 - File -> Options. Select the Add-Ins tab (Or go to Developer tab -> Add-Ins)
6 - At the bottom under "Manage" ensure "Excel Add-Ins" is selected in the combo box and select Go
7 - Browse... and find the .xlam file you just saved.
8 - The macros should now be loaded. You can test them out in a cell or go to Developer -> Visual Basic. In the Visual Basic Project panel on the left of the new window, your Add-In should appear along with your current workbook.
9 - You may be required to restart Excel before using the Add-In Macros.
```

Extra note:
To remove an unwanted Add-In (assuming you are are new to them as I am)

```
1 - File -> Options. Select the Add-Ins tab
2 - At the bottom under "Manage" ensure "Excel Add-Ins" is selected in the combo box and select Go
3 - Uncheck the Add-In you wish to remove. Going to the Developers tab -> Visual Basic should now display that the Add-In has been removed from the project.
```